# Disponibilidad de variables SASS en componentes React

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un fichero con variables de *Sass* en un proyecto *React*.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlas disponibles de forma global, es decir a todos los componentes, sin tener que hacer una importación específica en cada componente en que se usan?

> **Editado** 
>   Actualmente tengo un fichero con las variables
>   `'./src/assets/styles/vars.scss'` y ahora mismo lo importo en cada
>   componente que lo necesita en su fichero .scss con:
>   `@import '../../assets/styles/vars.scss'` en su primera línea

Comment: De poder se puede pero vas a querer evitarlo, ademas de ser complejo, para una integración mas transparente te recomiendo "CSS-IN-JSS", aprende de "styled components".

Comment: @Orici ¿Cómo estás importando el fichero con las variables SaSS?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro edito la pregunta y te contesto.